# How do you create a PDF document using iText that has pages with differing page sizes?

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

I am trying to create a PDF document using iText that has pages with differing page sizes. (That is, the PDF document may have several pages, some legal size, some letter size, in no particular order.)

Here is the code that I have that isn't working:

```
Document pdfDocument = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, ServletActionContext.getResponse().getOutputStream());
pdfDocument.open();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

  Rectangle pageSize = PageSize.LETTER;

  // Code removed... this is where I calculate what the pageSize is supposed to be... either PageSize.LETTER or PageSize.LEGAL

  pdfDocument.setPageSize(pageSize);
  pdfDocument.newPage();
  writer.setPageEmpty(false);

  // Code removed... this is where I add images to the page

}

pdfDocument.close();
```

Comment: pdfDocument.setPageSize(pageSize); is in your loop but the value does not change for each iteration.